# ember how to pass model data from controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have ember controller like this:

```
App.TripEditController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    init: function(){
        return this.store.find('trip', 1);
    }
});
```

how do I access the data from ember template. I can't use ember route because it is a modal and I am using fancy-box to popup that modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
App.TripEditController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    trip: null,
    init: function(){
        var self = this;
        self._super.apply(this, arguments);
        return self.store.find('trip', 1).then(function(trip){
            self.set('trip', trip);
        });
    }
});
```

You should then be able to use something like `{{trip}}` in your template

Comment: thanks @tikotzky for your quick response. your way is working fine. But from template I am displaying data like this:   **{{ trip._data.name}}** is there any way I can do: **{{name}}** or **{{trip.name}}**

Comment: Im not sure how your data looks but from what your asking you should be able to change `self.set('trip', trip);` to `self.set('trip', trip.data);` and then just user `{{trip.name}}`